# Updating Tvalue in a dictionary performance

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine

I was just designing something and was wondering if this was any bad programming practice after all.

If I were to have a Dictionary and have the Tvalue updating real-time(Here, I meant to say every frame or every physics frame), would I be terribly mistaken?

This 'design' is to, in the end, sort out a single GameObject out of the Dictionary index while the Tvalue being the comparing factor for the Tkeys to be sorted out for. I was doing this with List, but dictionary seemed more of a rational choice if I wanted to pair another value for their comparisons after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.1) documentation the performance of **Dictionary** for retrieving a value is close to *O(1)*, meaning that the time to retrieve an item is independent of the size (number of elements stored) of the Dictionary.

> Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1),
>   because the Dictionary class is implemented as a hash
>   table.

I don't know the details of your project but I think you can update the TValue in every frame without too much performance overhead.

Comment: Thanks! I was dead worried about this: multiple TValues updating within update tick rate sounded scary. I now know there was nothing to worry about 'retrieving,' just not too sure about the other way around, but at least the half of it is costless, I guess.